# Отложенные deeplink facebook android

Tags: android, facebook, deeplink

Мне нужно использовать отложенный deeplink в моем приложении для Android, но в следующем коде я получаю appLinkData = null

```
AppLinkData.fetchDeferredAppLinkData(this, getString(R.string.facebook_app_id),
            new AppLinkData.CompletionHandler() {
                @Override
                public void onDeferredAppLinkDataFetched(AppLinkData appLinkData) {
                    Log.d("SplashActivity", "appLinkData: " + appLinkData);
                }
            }
    );
```

I need use Deferred app deeplink in my Android app, but in next code i get appLinkData = null

```
AppLinkData.fetchDeferredAppLinkData(this, getString(R.string.facebook_app_id),
        new AppLinkData.CompletionHandler() {
            @Override
            public void onDeferredAppLinkDataFetched(AppLinkData appLinkData) {
                Log.d("SplashActivity", "appLinkData: " + appLinkData);
            }
        }
);
```

Если я использую уведомление то ссылка приходит

Я пробовал:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/app-ads/deep-linking 
https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/deep-linking

Но ничего из этого мне не помогло

Мой Manifest

```
<meta-data
        android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
        android:value="@string/facebook_app_id" />

<activity
        android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
        android:label="@string/app_name" />

<activity
        android:name="com.tanat.posture.SplashActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data android:scheme="posture"/>
        </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Мой SplashActivity

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);

    AppLinkData.fetchDeferredAppLinkData(this, getString(R.string.facebook_app_id),
            new AppLinkData.CompletionHandler() {
                @Override
                public void onDeferredAppLinkDataFetched(AppLinkData appLinkData) {
                    Log.d("SplashActivity", "appLinkData: " + appLinkData);
                }
            }
    );

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String action = intent.getAction();
    Uri data = intent.getData();
    Log.d("SplashActivity", "data: " + data);
}
```

Тестирую через https://developers.facebook.com/tools/app-ads-helper

с помощью ИНСТРУМЕНТ ДЛЯ ТЕСТИРОВАНИЯ ГЛУБОКИХ ССЫЛОК

Ссылку делаю такого вида

fb44567876302xxx4://test/123

Так же пробовал

posture://test/123 (как в манифесте в scheme)

Возможно есть рабочие примеры которые я не нашел?
Или есть какие то дополнительные условия о которых ни сказано в документации?

Comment: В процессе настройки есть очень много деталей. Я знаю человека, который через это всё не раз проходил, но он говорит, что у вас в вопросе слишком мало информации и нужно слишком много вам вопросов задавать, чтобы что-то ответить. Попробуйте добавить деталей. Например как вы отправляете уведомление, тестируете как. Приведите скрины, например, сайта лицокниги с указанием того что и как вы там нажимаете и что прописываете. Какие ключи подписи для приложения используете и прочая и прочая.

Comment: Вроде как оно должно работать так: 1. У приложения надо стереть все данные (не кэш, а всё), потом удалить его. 2. Перейти на сайт лицокниги и там отправить отложенный пуш. 3. Зайти в приложение лицокниги и перейти по уведомлению из п2. 4. Установить приложение из студии - в колюэк должна прийти ссылка. ||| Чтобы всё это работало в настройках приложения на сайте лицокниги должны быть прописаны пакет приложения, класс активити и указаны ключи подписи Тут надо их правильно сделать и не перепутать дебажные ключи с разных компов и/или ключи подписи различных магазинов приложений или релизного ключа

Answer (score -1):

я мучался над этим вопросом очень долго ) и перерыл кучу информации оказалось все просто  на телефоне на котором тестируешь deaplink должна быть установлена прила фб без нее линки не работают и приходит в лог всегда null